# mongoose sort by count of object id in diffrerent collection

Tags: sorting, mongoose, collections, count, objectid

I have a Collection of Articles, like

```
var articleSchema = new Schema(
{
    link: { type: String, required: true, unique: true  },
    title: { type: String },
    description: {type: String },
    source: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'sources' },
    … 
};
```

The Source links via objectId to the Source schema.

```
var sourceSchema = new Schema(
{
    name: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true },
    short_handle: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, unique: true },
    website: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, unique: true },
    …
}
```

What i want to do: querying the sources and sorting them by the amount of articles linked to that sources. Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are adding source reference to each article, you will need to query on `Article` model. Need to perform aggregation to get the required results in grouped and sorted order.

```
await Article
    .aggregate([

        { "$group": { 
            "_id": '$source', 
            "articleCount": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},

        { "$sort": { "articleCount": -1 } }
]);
```

This query returns a list of source and their related articles count in sorted order. In my case, here is the output.

```
[ { _id: 5b7c7cf407d686e60a07e4e1, articleCount: 4 },
  { _id: 5b7c7cc707d686e60a07e4df, articleCount: 2 },
  { _id: 5b7c7ce407d686e60a07e4e0, articleCount: 1 } ]
```

Comment: Sounds Pretty good! I didnt use .Aggregate yet tho, can i populate the ids within that query?

Comment: @GerritHillebrecht Yes, you can do it but it will do another query, check the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate and after performing the aggregation do this.
Article.populate(result, {path: "source"}, callback);

Comment: I didn't get the "articleCount" count part, are we getting the sum as well?